# Values with apostrophe are truncated

Tags: asp-classic

I have an issue where I pull values from a database. The values have apostrophe's in them but when they are displayed on the page the string stops at the apostrophe (i.e. today's is displayed as today).

How can I get the entire string to be displayed?

Here is where I am displaying the string:

Code:

```
<h1 class='tabletitle'><%=rs("FloorName")%> & nbsp;(<%=dspLayoutName%>)</h1>
```

The variable containing the apostrophe is "dspLayoutName".  It can come from either a DB or passed to the page.  I am using asp classic.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it didn't work. Here is what I did:
    < h1 class='tabletitle'>< %=rs("FloorName")%>&nbsp;(< %= Server.HTMLEncode(dspLayoutName) % >)< /h1>

Comment: Is the full string in the outputted HTML? What do you see when you view source in the browser? Are you sure you are getting the full string from the DB? Have you confirmed that the DB contains the full string?

Comment: First check that the full string has been entered into the database. If your code isn't somehow escaping single quotes (', which is not "an apostrophe") in strings then it may well be truncating at the single quote *during the data entry phase*.

If that's the case, then your database *reading* code is doing just fine; it's your *writing* code that contains the problem. To test this (assuming the field should contain "today's" but it returning "today") try this: `<p>Actual size is <%=rs("FloorName").actualSize%> bytes</p>` !f the response is "5" then you have a problem storing the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  Yes the apostrophe is in the DB.  Here is where I am having the problem < option value='< %=rs("LayoutName")%>'>< %=rs("LayoutName")%>< /option>.  The value is losing the apostrophe but the text is keeping it.

Comment: This is what I get when I view the source:  < OPTION value=Mona Layout? Test s>Mona's Test Layout< /OPTION>.  The value text is all messed up while the displayed text is fine.  WHY???   Where is the question mark (?) come from and words are out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would suggest you to do something like below

Use &#39 and put ';' after it, this will definitely work for you.

<%=Replace (rs("FloorName"), "'", "& #39;")%> instead of using <%=rs("FloorName")%>

I have put space between & and # inside replace function as it was returning single quote.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but I get the error, "Object expected" then it gives the line #

Comment: I believe rs("FloorName") does not have value which caused this. Try setting this to a variable and use that variable here.

Comment: I already did that but then I get the error "n is not defined".  Here is what I tried:  var str = rs("LayoutName");
                  var n=str.replace("'", "&#39;");
                  <option value='<%=n%>'><%=rs("LayoutName")%></option>

Comment: What I meant by using variable was var data = Replace (rs("FloorName"), "'", "& #39;") and use <%=data%>, to cross check print the length using Len(rs("FloorName"))

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried exactly what you suggested but the execution dies at the Replace line.  I don't get an error, it just stops and the rest of the controls after that line are not rendered.